# C# lock statement, what object to lock on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have 3 questions that I need help with.

1. What are the correct objects/references to be passed as `lock` statement parameter? I've seen a lot of sample codes and I noticed that the objects/references passed in could possibly be non related to the current class or any other class in the program as long as the access modifier `static` is non public? E.g.:

   ```
   private Object anyObj = new Object();
   lock(anyObj){.....}

   private static readonly object Locker = new object();
   lock(Locker){.....}
   ```

   It just doesn't make sense to me.
2. I found a sample code in MSDN about multi threading that uses `lock` statements too. In the sample there are two `try`/`catch` blocks with the `Monitor.Wait()` within it. If I understand the logic correctly, the `readerFlag` will forbid the program to ever enter the `try`/`catch` block at all.
   The code is example 2 from here:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx
3. How do I run a thread that runs in the background as long as the Windows Form is active?

Answer (score 84):

How and what you lock on depends upon what you're doing.

Let's say that you're working with a device of some kind - say a coffee maker.  You might have a class that looks like this:

```
public CoffeeMaker {
    private IntPtr _coffeeHandle;
    private Object _lock = new Object();
}
```

In this case, you are protecting access to the _coffeeHandle - a pointer/handle to a real physical device, so this is pretty easy:

```
public int AvailableCups {
    get {
        lock (_lock) {
            return GetAvailableCups(_coffeeHandle); // P/Invoked
        }
    }
}

public void Dispense(int nCups)
{
    lock (_lock) {
        int nAvail = GetAvailableCups(_coffeeHandle);
        if (nAvail < nCups) throw new CoffeeException("not enough coffee.");
        Dispense(_coffeeHandle, nCups); // P/Invoked
    }
 }
```

So if I'm running a multithreaded app, I (probably) don't want to read the number of cups that are available while I'm dispensing (maybe it's a hardware error).  By protecting accesses to the handle, I can ensure that.  Also, I can't be asked to dispense while I'm already dispensing - that would be bad, so that's protected too.  Finally, I don't dispense unless I have enough coffee available and you notice that I **don't** use my public property to check that - this way the action of ensuring there's enough coffee and dispensing are tied together.  The magic word is atomic - they can't be cut apart without creating issues.

You use a static object as a lock if you have one and only one instance of a resource that needs protecting.  Think, "do I have a singleton?" and that will be a guideline for when you might need a static lock.  For example, let's say that CoffeeMaker has a private constructor.  Instead, you have a factory method that constructs coffee machines:

```
static Object _factLock = new Object();

private CoffeeMaker(IntPtr handle) { _coffeeHandle = handle; }

public static CoffeeMaker GetCoffeeMaker()
{
    lock (_factLock) {
        IntPtr _handle = GetCoffeeMakerHandle(); // P/Invoked
        if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
        return new CoffeeMaker(_handle);
    }
 }
```

Now in this case, it feels like CoffeeMaker should [implement IDisposable](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2006/09/21/10887.aspx) so that handle gets taken care of, because if you don't release it then somebody might not be getting their coffee.

There are a few problems though - maybe if there's not enough coffee, we should make more - and that takes a long time.  Heck - dispensing coffee takes a long time, which is why we're careful to protect our resources.  Now you're thinking that really all this coffee maker stuff should be in a thread of its own and that there should be an event that gets fired when the coffee is done, and then it starts to get complicated and you understand the importance of knowing what you're locking on and when so that you don't block making coffee because you asked how many cups are there.

And if the words "deadlock", "atomic", "monitor", "wait", and "pulse" all sound foreign to you, you should consider reading up on multiprocessing/multithreading in general and see if you can solve [the fair barbershop problem](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lorenzo/corsi/cs372h/07S/labs/labT/labT.html) or [the dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem), both quintessential examples of resource contention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer plinth, there is so much to take in. I'll need to really read this up properly. :)

Comment: This is an excellent and very complete example.  Deserves way more upvotes than it has!

Comment: This is actually a very poor example. `IntPtr` is a `struct`. As a value type, it gets boxed if you use it with `lock`. This means each call to `lock (_coffeeHandle)` gets a different object instance, which means _zero_ synchronization. It is unfortunate this answer got (by far) the most up-votes, as it is the least useful/most harmful of the bunch.

Comment: Hey - nice catch - _lock was there, just wasn't being used in the lock statement.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I found the post useful (coming from no multithreading background), and your explanation of what happens when you lock on a value type useful as well. After plinth's edit, is anything else exceptionally in err?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `lock (_coffeeHandle)`?

Answer (score 38):

1) your code is incomplete. You always lock around a certain (shared) resource. The `anyObject` should have a close 1-1 correspondence in lifetime with that shared object.

For instance:

a) the simple but most direct pattern:

```
List<MyClass> sharedList = ...;
...
lock (sharedList) { sharedList.Add(item); }
```

there is a drawback in this pattern: what if other code also locks on `sharedList` for other reasons? Usually not a practical problem, but it is the reason that the recommended pattern is (b):

```
List<MyClass> sharedList = ...;
private object listLock = new object();
...
lock (listLock) { sharedList.Add(item); }
```

Or, when the shared object is static (c) :

```
static List<MyClass> sharedList = ...;
private static object listLock = new object();
...
lock (listLock) { sharedList.Add(item); }
```

2) The threads alternate setting `readerFlag` to true or false so the try/catch blocks will be entered. The synchronization is done with Monitor.Pulse() and .Wait(). Note that Wait() will yield the lock for the duration s there is no deadlock.

Comment: Hi Henk, I can't thank you enough for your quick reply. So in summary, can i say that the private member(lockList) is just there so that i can lock it in a proper way? If thats the case, i can just blindly just create a private member(such as lockList) whenever i use lock statements?

Comment: As for the sample code, initially the readerFlag was false. So when the threads are executed, the WriteToCell method is called first. But since the flag is false it doesn't go into the try catch block. It then change the flag to true and the ReadFromCell is executed also causing the try catch block not to be executed. I don't see when the try catch is executed? Did i get the flow wrong? Thank you so so much!

Comment: You are right that the sample code is not the easiest to follow. Note that the 2nd call to Write will enter the try-catch and call Wait(). Also note you can run and debug this, it's a complete program.

Comment: _just create a private member whenever i use lock statements_ No, the lockObject belongs to the shared resource, not to the lock statement. It's very important all related `lock`s use the same object.

Comment: Arrgghh this is so confusing having this private member. Sorry for being so silly. I still don't really get how it works. Can you give me a url or something?

Comment: @Henk regarding the first pattern, even if other code locks it then you can't access the shared list. But, That is the required thing. Am I correct

Comment: Same question as @prabhakaran. What is the advantage of using a separate lock object as in b), instead of just locking the object you intent to access in a synchonized manner as in a)? Can you give an example of the 'drawback' of pattern a)?

Comment: locking solves race conditions but it can cause deadlocks. To prevent deadlocks you have to carefully manage who can locks on a certain resource. Using a private lock object helps there.

Answer (score 7):

1: the object you use defines / is-defined-by the lock granularity you are trying to enforce. If is is "anything calling against the current instance", then a `private readonly object syncLock = new object()` would be reasonable. If it is "any code, regardless of the instance" (static, in particular), then `private readonly static object syncLock = new object()`. Sometimes there is an obvious "thing" you are trying to protect that will also serve: a list, a queue, etc. The main **wrong** decisions are: `this`, `typeof(...)`, any `string`, any value-type that you are boxing for each `lock`, and anything that you have leaked outside of the instance.

2: `Monitor.Wait` **releases** the locks from the current thread, waiting for either a "pulse" or a timeout, at which point it wakes up and joins the queue to *regain* to locks it had (note the "s" there is for re-entrancy). That means that two threads can use a `Monitor` to *signal* between themselves, by pulsing and waiting.

3: unrelated; but basically "check a flag periodically, and when being pulsed"

Answer (score 4):

According the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx):

> The argument provided to the **lock** keyword ... is used to define the scope of the lock. ...Strictly speaking, the
>   object provided is used solely to uniquely identify the resource being
>   shared among multiple threads, so it can be an arbitrary class
>   instance. In practice, however, this object usually represents the
>   resource for which thread synchronization is necessary.

In my case, I have passed the exact static object that I have needed to change.