# Any guidance of deciding a particular object for locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have seen few different ways of using a particular object for lock construct.

1. Have a dedicated private static local variable and lock on that

   ```
   private static object syncObj = new object();  
   ...  
   lock(syncObj)  
   {

   }
   ```
2. Have a dedicated private local variable and lock on that

   ```
   private object syncObj = new object();  
   ...  
   lock(syncObj)  
   {

   }
   ```
3. Another one is to use the object itself.

   ```
   private List<MyClass> SomeObjects = new List<MyClass>();  
   ....  
   lock(SomeObjects)  
   {  

   }
   ```
4. One approach is to use the type of a particular object.

   ```
   private List<MyClass> SomeObjects = new List<MyClass>();  
    ...    
   lock(SomeObjects.GetType())  
   {  

   }
   ```
5. Another possibility is using lock(this) but general recommendation seem to try to avoid using this.

My questions.
1. Are there any other ways of using objects for locks?
2. How can I decide of what approach should be used for a particular scenario?

Comment: Locking on an instance of `Type` and/or on `this` are bad ideas because you don't know who else is locking on the same thing.

Comment: I have never heard of a `private static local variable`, what is this creature?

Comment: As it has been said by @Preston Guillot, your question is a possible duplicate, but loosely speaking, you're possibly best having a dedicated object. Whether it should be static or not depends on whether or not it matters if multiple instances of your object use the same resources. For instance, if you're locking to ensure thread-safety when modifying an instance list, having a static locking object may not be necessary. Locking on (3) the object, (4) the type of the object, or (5) `this` all have very similar drawbacks as you have no idea who might also be locking on the same objects.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: actually, while it is kind of a duplicate of that other question, the leading-vote-getter answer is so bad that I cringe at the thought of closing this question as a duplicate of it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Marc Gravell's answer to [C# lock statement, what object to lock on?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764062/3538012) were the top vote-getter (and it should have been, IMHO), I would happily have voted to close this question as a duplicate.

But, it's not. And this question does have some minor differences in context. So…

Taking your five examples in particular:

> 1. Have a dedicated private static local variable and lock on that

This works well for scenarios where you have some static member that needs to be synchronized. A common implementation convention in .NET is to make all static members thread-safe, and for types which are not themselves specifically targeting multi-threaded code, to not bother making instance members thread-safe.

Note that the declaration should be `static readonly`, to ensure that the locking object remains the same through the lifetime of the program.

> 2. Have a dedicated private local variable and lock on that

This is better for protecting instance members, in a class that is specifically supposed to be thread-safe. While a `static` lock object would also work, that can be needlessly contentious. That is, private instance members are generally safe from other instances of the object touching them, as classes usually only operate on their own instance members, not those of other instances.

A `static` lock object would require all threads operating on *any* instance to synchronize their execution, when it would be safe for threads using different instances to operate concurrently.

As with the `static` lock object, make the field `readonly`.

> 3. Another one is to use the object itself.

I tend to try to avoid doing this. If the object is maintained privately, and you are sure that the reference is never known to any other code other than your own and that within the object itself, it can be safe enough. But it can be risky, as you can't be sure even if the object is currently never used elsewhere that the code will never change such that it later.

If the reference were to become available outside your own class, then it's possible some other code could also lock on the object in an inopportune way. The worst would be if it acquired some other lock, then tried to lock on that object, while your own code tried to acquire the other lock having already locked on that object. Deadlock. Less bad is simply increasing thread contention on the lock. The code would still work, but may not run as well.

> 4. One approach is to use the type of a particular object

This combines the worst of the above: publicly available reference, static member. Strongly advised *against*.

> 5. Another possibility is using lock(this) but general recommendation seem to try to avoid using this.

This is just a variation on #3, except that you are practically guaranteed that the reference will be used by some other code. Not advised.

You can, in the sense that "it is possible", use any reference with a `lock` statement (i.e. any `class` value…you definitely *should not use* any `struct` value, as suggested in the answer to the question which Preston has suggested as a duplicate for this one). However, there are lots of ways to get this wrong.

IMHO, the best policy is to keep it simple: match the static/instance declaration of whatever it is you're trying to protect (either a whole object, or in some cases specific operations on a specific object), always make the field `readonly`, and be done with it.